# Playing audio concurrently in Ionic with ngCordova Native Audio plugin

Tags: android, cordova, audio, ionic-framework

I'm building an Ionic app that needs to play multiple audio loops at the same time.

In my project, I've implemented the cordova native audio plugin (http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/nativeAudio/) and it works great when playing one sound. However when I try to play 2 sounds in a loop at the same time it only plays the second sound.

```js
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
  window.plugins.NativeAudio.preloadComplex('soundA', 'media/sounds/soundA.mp3', 1, 1, 0);
  window.plugins.NativeAudio.preloadComplex('soundB', 'media/sounds/soundB.mp3', 1, 1, 0);

  window.plugins.NativeAudio.loop('soundA');
  window.plugins.NativeAudio.loop('soundB');
});
```

According to the plugin documentation, it should be able to handle concurrency. The example on the documentation is an example of 2 tracks playing at once. I've done the same but it isn't working. I'm testing this on Android.

If anyone has anyone knows how to fix this issue it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You've tried with the function `preloadSimple` instead of `preloadComplex` to reproduce the sounds?

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap your `window.plugins.NativeAudio.loop` calls with `$timeout`. I have the feeling that `preloadComplex` have some delay to instantiate.

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
  window.plugins.NativeAudio.preloadComplex('soundA', 'media/sounds/soundA.mp3', 1, 1, 0);
  window.plugins.NativeAudio.preloadComplex('soundB', 'media/sounds/soundB.mp3', 1, 1, 0);

  $timeout(function(){
    window.plugins.NativeAudio.loop('soundA');
    window.plugins.NativeAudio.loop('soundB');
  })
});
```